# CSS not displaying in old versions of IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

We are still using an old version of SharePoint (2007) and I have begun to try and learn how you use CSS and Content Editor WebParts (CEWPs) to adjust the way some of our lists work. I am trying to create a small row of drop downs within a web part that will have hyperlinks to sections. This is the HTML code I am using which displays correctly via Chrome:

```css
#primary_nav_wrap
{
 margin-top:15px
}

#primary_nav_wrap ul
{
 list-style:none;
 position:relative;
 float:left;
 margin:0;
 padding:0
}

#primary_nav_wrap ul a
{
 display:block;
 color:#333;
 text-decoration:none;
 font-weight:700;
 font-size:12px;
 line-height:32px;
 padding:0 15px;
 font-family:"HelveticaNeue","Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif
}

#primary_nav_wrap ul li
{
 position:relative;
 float:left;
 margin:0;
 padding:0
}

#primary_nav_wrap ul li.current-menu-item
{
 background:#ddd
}

#primary_nav_wrap ul li:hover
{
 background:#f6f6f6
}

#primary_nav_wrap ul ul
{
 display:none;
 position:absolute;
 top:100%;
 left:0;
 background:#fff;
 padding:0
}

#primary_nav_wrap ul ul li
{
 float:none;
 width:200px
}

#primary_nav_wrap ul ul a
{
 line-height:120%;
 padding:10px 15px
}

#primary_nav_wrap ul ul ul
{
 top:0;
 left:100%
}

#primary_nav_wrap ul li:hover > ul
{
 display:block
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="test.css" />
</head>
<body>

<h1>Simple Pure CSS Drop Down Menu</h1>
<nav id="primary_nav_wrap">
<ul>
  <li class="current-menu-item"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Menu 1</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 3</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 4</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Deep Menu 1</a>
            <ul>
              <li><a href="#">Sub Deep 1</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Sub Deep 2</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Sub Deep 3</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Sub Deep 4</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Deep Menu 2</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 5</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Menu 2</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 3</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Menu 3</a>
    <ul>
      <li class="dir"><a href="#">Sub Menu 1</a></li>
      <li class="dir"><a href="#">Sub Menu 2 THIS IS SO LONG IT MIGHT CAUSE AN ISSEUE BUT MAYBE NOT?</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Category 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Category 2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Category 3</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Category 4</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Category 5</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 3</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 4</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 5</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Menu 4</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Menu 5</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Menu 6</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
</ul>
</nav>

</body>
</html>
```

For some reason when I put this into a CEWP and use IE it doesn't use the CSS code at all and displays as HTML, but if I open the same page in Chrome is displays fine.

Can anyone offer any suggestions on how I can get old versions of IE to display this bit of CSS within MOSS 2007 please?

Comment: SharePoint 2007 definitely does not support HTML5. Even SharePoint 2010 has issues with it (SharePoint 2007 was developed around the same time IE7 was developed, and that was almost 10 years ago; Microsoft doesn't even make IE anymore). Likewise, old versions of Internet Explorer don't support newer CSS features. First, try adding `type="text/css"` to your CSS `<link>` in the <head>`. If that doesn't work, you'll need to let us know exactly which version of IE you start to see the problems on.

Comment: As well as changing the css `link` tag, changing `<nav id="primary_nav_wrap"></nav>` to `<div id="primary_nav_wrap"></div>` will help a lot